# Why does my age calculation include a DAY comparison?

Tags: sas

Here is the code. My explanation of what I think it does (and some context on the dataset it manipulates) follows below the code.

```
 If DOB ne . then do;                                                                                                                                      
        Tage=Floor(intck('month',DOB,SpecimenDate)-(Day(SpecimenDate)<Day(DOB)));                                                                              
        If TAge < 12 then Age=TAge/12;                                                                                                                         
     End;                                                                                                                                                      
     Else Age=Int(TAge/12);                                                                                                                                    

     If Age <= 0 then Age=.;                                                                                                                                   
     If Age >110 then Age=.;
```

My understanding of the code is that if DOB (date of birth) is not missing, then create a variable "tage" which is a function of DOB and SpecimenDate (i.e., when the individual submitted a stool, blood, or urine specimen for laboratory testing). Basically, I know that this code is attempting to calculate a person's age at the time of specimen submission, but I'm not sure how it is done, or if the code is erroneous.

More specifically, it appears that we are looking for the number of months between the subject's date of birth and the date they submitted a specimen minus the day of the specimen date or the day of the date of birth? And then whichever value is largest but <= the argument is returned? The part of the argument that I really don't understand is

```
(Day(SpecimenDate)<Day(DOB)
```

(NB: I understand the code beyond this particular line, but am including all the code to establish the context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard way of calculating month or year difference in dates (hence why it wasn't commented I guess - this is very common).  Until recently, this was the simplest way to calculate ages or other month/year intervals where you want to only count completed intervals.

Breaking this out:

`intck('month',DOB,SpecimenDate)` returns the number of months between DOB and SpecimenDate, with the caveat that 'number of months' really means 'number of 1sts of the month'.

`Day(SpecimenDate)<Day(DOB)` returns a 1 (true) if the SpecimenDate is on a day-of-the-month less than the DOB.  So if it's the 15th of the month when the specimen is collected, and my birthday is the 23rd of (any) month, it's a 1.

That's because intck('month','23JAN1994'd,'15MAR1994'd) returns 2, not 1, month between them due to how `intck` works by default.

Post 9.2, you can now use the "method" optional fourth option in `intck` to make this work natively without the extra code.

`intck('month',SpecimenDate,DOB,'c')`  -> Continuous, so returns 1
`intck('month',SpecimenDate,DOB,'d')` (or left out) -> Discrete, so returns 2

To calculate age directly, you could now do `intck('year',SpecimenDate,DOB,'c')`, although your code looks like it wants to know the fractional age for infants under 1, which would require a second piece of code in any event.